# optional substring character

Tags: xpath

I'm using XSLT 1.0

I have a node that sometimes has a ~ in it:

```
<node id="123~001"/>
```

And sometimes it doesn't:

```
<node id="123"/>
```

I'm wondering if the substring-before command allows for optional characters?  If it doesn't what is the best way to check to see if the ~ exists or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an -, then there always is one:

```
substring-before(concat(@id, "-"), "-")
```